# IF statements in batch files

Tags: windows, environment-variables, cmd.exe

I am currently using Cruise Control to schedule 'builds' for various internal websites.   I use batch files to kick off each of these 'builds' (build meaning a specific webhelp output).   Let's say for example purposes, we have builds labeled Internal, External and Public.   Inside  of the master batch file, you would find the following code:

```
if x%TargetName:-Internal-=%==x%TargetName%  goto ReplaceNav
if x%TargetName:-External-=%==x%TargetName% goto SkipSearch 
if x%TargetName:-Public-=%==x%TargetName% goto SkipSearch
:: do not uncomment or the skin will not get copied to the output
```

So, let me explain what is going on here..   The variable %TargetName% is already set to a value before this part of the script runs.   The variable %TargetName% will contain the text -Internal, -External or -Public and will have other characters at the beginning or end of each target name, but the thing I want to be able to have a conditional statement for is if the script sees -Internal in the %TargetName% variable, the script will then skip to a code block labeled :ReplaceNav.   Here is what :ReplaceNav looks like.

```
:ReplaceNav
echo.
echo -----------------------------------------------------------------
echo Replacing Navigation.htm and Search.htm files
echo TargetName is %TargetName%
echo CurrUser is %CurrUser%
echo -----------------------------------------------------------------
echo.

pushd ..\..\some\dir\MasterPages

    copy /y "Navigation1.COPY" "..\..\..\Output\%CurrUser%\%TargetName%\Skin\Navigation.htm" 2>&1
    IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
        echo.
        echo Failed to replace Navigation.htm file with Exit Code: %ERRORLEVEL%
        echo.
        exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%
    )
    copy /y "Search.COPY" "..\..\..\Output\%CurrUser%\%TargetName%\Skin\Search.htm" 2>&1
    IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
        echo.
        echo Failed to replace Search.htm file with Exit Code: %ERRORLEVEL%
        echo.
        exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%
    )
popd
```

ReplaceNav essentially replaces two files in the webhelp output with a two custom pages that contain a search engine that is only available to internal users.

If the variable %TargetName% contains -External or -Public, the batch file SHOULD skip to the :SkipSearch section of the batch file.

```
:SkipSearch
echo.
echo -----------------------------------------------------------------
echo Skipped Search and Navigation Replacement
echo -----------------------------------------------------------------
echo.
```

My issue is as follows (and I am pretty sure it has to do with not structuring the IF statement properly): How do I structure this code block

```
if x%TargetName:-Internal-=%==x%TargetName%  goto ReplaceNav
if x%TargetName:-External-=%==x%TargetName% goto SkipSearch 
if x%TargetName:-Public-=%==x%TargetName% goto SkipSearch
:: do not uncomment or the skin will not get copied to the output
```

to properly step through the %TargetName% variable to see if it has the value of -Internal, -External or -Public and then skip to the correct code block in my script?   Currently, it seems to evaluate the

```
if x%TargetName:-Internal-=%==x%TargetName%  goto ReplaceNav
```

statement, but no matter what it is replacing the navigation pages on builds with -External and -Public as well :(   I should also mention that this if statement was not written by me at all and if you can think of some other way to parse the %TargetName% variable for -Internal, -Public or -External I am all for it.

I do understand this that is kind of a strange question, so please let me know if you need any further details in order to answer.

Comment: Any good reason you're not doing this in PowerShell?

Comment: Not really..   Just not very good with powershell and these scripts were written before I took over the task of managing this project at work.

Comment: and that being said, is there a really easy way to do that sort of thing in powershell?  if there is, I might be interested trying to turn these into powershell scripts if someone can point me towards a solution that works in PS.

Comment: I think you'd be a lot happier if you did. You could actually use parameters and switches rather than parsing a string. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj554301.aspx Not to mention it would be _much_ more readable.

Comment: @Richie086: Besides what dbenham said below about the extra hyphens, try placing `echo`s before all 3 `if`s and see what values are printed out for `x%TargetName:-Internal-=%`, `x%TargetName:-External-=%`, `x%TargetName:-Public-=%` and `x%TargetName%`.

Answer (score 2):

You say you are looking for `-Internal`, but your search and replace is looking for `-Internal-`. This is true for all your search and replace operations. I suspect it may work if you simply remove the unwanted trailing `-` from the searches.

```
if x%TargetName:-Internal=%==x%TargetName%  goto ReplaceNav
if x%TargetName:-External=%==x%TargetName% goto SkipSearch 
if x%TargetName:-Public=%==x%TargetName% goto SkipSearch
:: do not uncomment or the skin will not get copied to the output
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you say PowerShell would be acceptable, I would encourage going that route.

I am not 100% sure what you are doing here, but here is an example script that I believe would do part of what you are asking. You can then decide if you would like to migrate more towards Powershell.

Check if the targetName contains "Internal":

```
If ($TargetName -Contains "Internal")
  {
    FunctionReplaceNav($TargetName)
  }
```

So that is a little more stright forward and easy to read. Then, again as more of an outline then the final code:

You could do additional processing on the replace in a function (Or inline you wanted in the original If Statement) like:

```
$CopyVariableName = Copy-Item Object.Ext copyToDirectory\Folder
if (!($CopyVariable))
   {
    Write-Host "Something Went wrong copying: $TargetName"
   }
else 
   {
    #Nothing here, moves along
    }
```

Of course, we could also make the error catching much more robust, for example by using a Try, Catch, Finally and catching any system execptions like Access denied, target machine unreachable, etc..

Comment: Ill give this a try tomorrow.  Any idea how to do positional parameters in powershell?  Like %1 %2 %3.